# How to plot a stacked bar with plotly, from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I have a df as

```
name | week |      %
mike   Week 1     .45
mike   Week 2      0
mike   Week 3     .40
mike   Week 4     .15
cindy  Week 1     .25
cindy  Week 2     .25
cindy  Week 3     .25
cindy  Week 4     .25
```

sampled df where my actual df has many more names

I am trying to plot all of the values of each name per week,

my plotly code is below:

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    names= df['name'].unique()
    
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Bar(name='Week 1', x=names, y=[.15, .29, .19, .07]),
        go.Bar(name='Week 2', x=names, y=[.24, .15, .15, .15]),
        go.Bar(name='Week 3', x=names, y=[.20, .19, .17, .11]),
        go.Bar(name='Week 4', x=names, y=[.41, .37, .49, .67]),
    
    
    ])
    # Change the bar mode
    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', title = 'title',xaxis_title='Month',
                      yaxis=dict(
            tickformat="%",
        ))

fig.show()
```

But I do not want to manually type out in y each of the values for week 1 then week 2 then week 3 and so on. How can I create a reference where y for each week in the plotting code will refer to all the values in week 1 so I dont have to type out? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The easiest way, is with `plotly.express`, which takes a tidy (long) dataframe, by column name.
- [plotly: Bar chart with Long Format Data](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/)

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
data = {'name': ['mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'cindy', 'cindy', 'cindy', 'cindy'],
        'week': ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4'],
        '%': [0.45, 0.0, 0.4, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
    name    week     %
0   mike  Week 1  0.45
1   mike  Week 2  0.00
2   mike  Week 3  0.40
3   mike  Week 4  0.15
4  cindy  Week 1  0.25
5  cindy  Week 2  0.25
6  cindy  Week 3  0.25
7  cindy  Week 4  0.25

# plot the long (tidy) dataframe
fig = px.bar(df, x="name", y="%", color="week", title="Title", barmode='stack')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Name', yaxis=dict(tickformat="%",))
fig.show()
```

- `plotly.graph_objects` requires a `plotly.graph_obj`, to construct each level of the stacked bar plot
- Using a list-comprehension, a `df.groupby` object can be unpacked into the necessary form, for `go.Figure`

  - As also mentioned in a comment by [Juan Estevez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9142735/juan-estevez)

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# using df from above, use groupby and a list comprehension to create data
data = [go.Bar(name=group, x=dfg['name'], y=dfg['%']) for group, dfg in df.groupby(by='week')]

# plot the figure
x = go.Figure(data)
x.update_layout(barmode='stack', title='Title', xaxis_title='Name', yaxis=dict(tickformat="%",))
x.show()
```

- Both implementations produce the following plot

[image]